# Tag Docker image with any other uniqe ID for Microservices - single Repository and single Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, microservices, docker-image

I am working on building a Jenkins pipeline that should tag docker image with unique id and pushes it to repository. The challenge is we are working on TIBCO micro services (around 15 developers) and everyone commits code and build happens with mvn (pom differs for each service) and build docker image with generated *.ear. As I am not sure which service will be picked up first, I want to get unique ID either from git or jenkins to tag image.

I have tried below options:

1.) I have tried other answers to get git commit id - most of them using latest commit id, which does not work in my case as multiple developers commit code.

2.) Jenkins Build ID- as we have same pipeline for multiple services - it is not getting incremental number for particular service.

Currently, we are using Udeploy which have in built repo that creates folder for each service and store incremental version inside it and now we are migrating to Containerization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We usually use the git branch + Build ID to make a unique identifier. An UUID is also a good start + Branch Name or something similar.

Comment: Git is not going to be any help here: you get a Git hash ID from a name, and either the name is already unique to that commit (so you didn't have a problem in the first place) or it's not (so you don't get something useful from Git here: e.g., you get the latest commit ID, not what you needed). So you'll definitely have to go outside Git.